# NGINX Reverse Proxy: 20:unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl

I am running nginx and i want to proxy another https host and to verify it's certificate.
I've created a CA cert, created a cert for the proxied host and signed it with the CA. The CA cert was added to the server's root certificates.

My nginx config is the following:

```
    proxy_ssl_verify_depth 1; # tried 0,1,2,3
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ca.pem;
    proxy_ssl_verify on;
```

When a request is done, nginx log returns:

```
[error] 26578#26578: *2 upstream SSL certificate verify error: (20:unable to get local issuer certificate) while SSL handshaking to upstream
```

Running openssl s_client -connect 1.1.1.1:8000 returns:

```
    CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = CY, ST = CY, L = CY, O = TEST.TEST, CN = TEST.TEST, emailAddress = admin@test.test
verify return:1
depth=0 C = CY, ST = CY, L = CY, O = TEST.TEST, OU = TEST.TEST, CN = 1.1.1.1
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=CY/ST=CY/L=CY/O=TEST.TEST/OU=test.test/CN=1.1.1.1
   i:/C=CY/ST=CY/L=CY/O=TEST.TEST/CN=test.test/emailAddress=admin@test.test
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.... cer
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=CY/ST=CY/L=CY/O=TEST.TEST/OU=test.test/CN=1.1.1.1
issuer=/C=CY/ST=CY/L=CY/O=TEST.TEST/CN=test.test/emailAddress=admin@test.test
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1491 bytes and written 415 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 94195986FED8C203B09C6A3870DC8B972A6FB3C98D69868CFAF9C4BFC2B7A714
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: D804526744415E7E6C3E0AFBAF4F5BB3B6315BE8785C46FCF7AA232A31E6D7C780E7A8D4B8413BE8D1F1758CF8DD8FE8
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 0a 5f b9 15 a5 78 d0 6c-32 24 77 3b 16 7a 10 75   ._...x.l2$w;.z.u
    0010 - 76 ed 08 18 8b 23 a8 15-24 3f eb 83 d8 6e 56 d6   v....#..$?...nV.
    0020 - 98 13 c2 36 62 35 17 42-b4 f9 e9 f7 99 50 14 77   ...6b5.B.....P.w
    0030 - 8b a3 e6 b5 2f ef ca af-7d 25 7c d8 7e b8 3a 96   ..../...}%|.~.:.
    0040 - 11 87 b2 e2 0a d6 de b6-60 75 c5 4a 58 57 8b 1b   ........`u.JXW..
    0050 - 73 6d 36 c6 9f 6a ec 31-71 2d 02 ad 50 45 8a 14   sm6..j.1q-..PE..
    0060 - 01 c1 6c 4a 2f 46 9b cb-e6 4c 09 97 17 fa 46 f4   ..lJ/F...L....F.
    0070 - 29 e6 a5 cb a7 37 fb 31-b3 a0 d7 55 ac cb fd 59   )....7.1...U...Y
    0080 - 42 a5 7b 45 9a 53 24 90-52 8c 8e 1c eb c4 db f9   B.{E.S$.R.......
    0090 - 27 04 b9 7e ba 0a 2d 9e-3b 92 67 ec 42 d6 69 78   '..~..-.;.g.B.ix

    Start Time: 1527255600
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

IP/cert names replaced by dummy versions in this result.

curl https://1.1.1.1 also works without problems.

I've been reading googling and checking all similar stackoverflow questions, but none of the proposed fixes seemed to resolve this.

Comment: What is the output of `openssl version`, `nginx -v`, and `cat /etc/issue`?

Comment: @rbhitchcock: `\S
Kernel \r on an \m` and `OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017`. Thank you!

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: I'm afraid i have not found any solutions.